# strange table out of box error in IE8

Tags: css

If you go here: [cmcp.dk](http://cmcp.dk/) with IE8 and choose english from left side, you will notice that News appears out of the background in IE8:

[image]

Solved. Putting divs inside those tds and played with size.

Answer (score 0):

The `<td>` that holds the content of that box has a `<table>` in it, the td width is 153px, but for some reason the table inside it is 165px, which is probably why this is being displayed as it is.

Comment: Yeah, already remarked that, changed that table to 153px but this does not seem to be the solution.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to 153 or to something smaller? try changing the inner table width to 140 just to see if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about re-slicing the background slightly and using divs instead. Table based design shouldn't really be used anymore and while rebuilding the site isn't really possible this would be a good chance to experiment with the concept.

Slice the top of the box, slice a 1px high middle bit and slice a footer. Use 3 divs and stack them on top of each other. Set the width needed - some padding to position your content then dump it all inside.

Comment: well..of course this can be done...but I would prefer to find the solution for this case instead of spending hours of replacing tables with divs

Comment: I was thinking just in this case, it should only take 10 minutes. I spent a while trying to figure out why it is doing what it is doing and couldn't, hence my alternative.